# opencl: clCreateBuffer() gives the memory object in host or device?

Tags: opencl

The buffer object is created using `clCreateBuffer()`, But where does that reside? And how to control this location?

Answer (score 0):

Its created in the targeted device(s)(you are choosing it yourself righT? otherwise a first visible device is chosen automatically) memory but it can be mapped to host memory for i/o operations. When you are creating it, you give the creation function flags like CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR and alike.

Take a look at : [AMD's opencl tutorial](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-resources/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/) and  [NVIDIA's](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vetter/keeneland/tutorial-2011-04-14/06-intro_to_opencl.pdf)

For example, I'm using

```
        deviceType=CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU;
        memoryModel=CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR;// uses host memory pointer
```

to compile on my CPU and

```
        deviceType=CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;
        memoryModel=CL_MEM_READ_WRITE;   // on GPU memory.
```

for discrete GPU to try some GL-CL interoperability tests.

```
     clCreateBuffer(context,memoryModel,Sizeof.cl_float * numElms), null, null);
```

When buffer is not on host memory and if you need to alter values in that buffer, you need explicit buffer copies/writes. When mapped, you dont need explicit read/write to host memory. Mapping also can give some i/o performance through DMA access for some systems.